# Получить значение localStorage расширения на любом сайте

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Есть тестовое расширение под chrome. Добавил в него несколько настроек. Они прекрасно сохраняются и передаются на background page. Но я никак не могу понять, как я могу использовать эти значения на сайте. Например в зависимости от настройки - добавить класс к боди на нужном мне сайте.

Вот как я делаю. в скрипте option.js я задаю localStorage

```
localStorage.power_status = document.getElementById('power_status').checked;
```

Это чекбокс. В итоге localStorage.power_status получает значение true/false

код в background такой:

```
var pwr_s = localStorage.power_status;

    chrome.storage.sync.set({'power_s':pwr_s}, function() {
        console.log('Option power set: ' + pwr_s);
    });
```

на сайте подключаю script.js, в нем пытаюсь получить значение:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('power_s', function(r) {
    console.log('Status: ' + r['power_s']);
});
```

Но значение получает не верное, или через раз.. т.е. не понятно откуда оно берется.. то верное показывает, то нет..

Может есть способ более простой манипулировать DOM через настройки расширения?

Итоговая задача состоит в том, что бы менять CSS стили на сайте в зависимости от настроек расширения. Планирую просто добавлять нужный класс к боди.

Comment: У бекграунда свое хранилище, у вашей странички своё. Дабы результат был одинаков - все должен делать фоновый скрипт( он же background) а content уже читает непосредственно с него

Comment: т.е. на сайте так же подключать background.js ?

Answer (score 1):

Идея с localStorage звучит крайне сложно, с учетом вашей задачи:

> Итоговая задача состоит в том, что бы менять CSS стили на сайте в зависимости от настроек расширения

Для того чтобы, вносить изменения в стили страницы вам достаточно методов [`chrome.tabs.insertCSS`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS) или [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)
В таком случае сайту даже не обязательно взаимодействовать и вообще знать про наличие расширения.

**Примеры**

Можно выполнить JS-код, меняющий стиль элемента:

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
});
```

Или добавить класс элементу:

```js
сhrome.tabs.executeScript({
  code: 'document.body.classList.add("myClass")'
});
```

Метод `insertCSS` позволяет добавлять произвольные стили на страницу:

```js
chrome.tabs.insertCSS({
    code: 'body {background: green}'
});
```

Или инъектировать собственный CSS-файл, упакованный вместе с расширением:

```js
chrome.tabs.insertCSS({
    file: 'style.css'
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! У меня нету проблем с изменением css или js на сайте. Я хочу сохранять эти изменения в настройках расширения. Вот в чем мой вопрос )